# Read base64 string from file now working, .read() return empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

When trying to read the contents of a file, the read result is empty, the content of the file is a base64 string.

- Tried to reset the reader to line 0 (file.seek(0), but im already opening the file in read "r" mode.
- Verified that the path actually exists and the file is not empty.

```
def readb64(file_path):

   script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
   rel_path = file_path
   abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)

   data = open(abs_file_path, 'r').read()

   print(data) # It is empty

   nparr = np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(data), np.uint8)
   img = cv.imdecode(nparr, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

   return img
```

*** Example of path *** (abs_file_path): /Users/duarteandrade/Desktop/TEMP-DEMO/Python/base-adonis-vue/resources/pythonScripts/base64_json/edfe8ef460.txt

I want to be able to read the base64 string so i can convert it to a image.

Comment: try to open with `data = open(abs_file_path, 'rb').read()`

Comment: @beer44 it return " b'' ", could this because of blackslashes or something ?

Comment: `print(abs_file_path)` and check if it's the same as the one that you look at (or the contents that you see is actually saved on disk).

Comment: @CristiFati Yes it is, tried with different files and verified more than once